# Matrices $A, B, C$ such that $AB=BC=CA$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Are there any invertible, distinct $n \times n$ matrices $A, B, C$ over $\mathbb C$ such that $AB=BC=CA$ but $A^2 \neq \lambda I_n$?

Comment: Possible Hint: Consider $ABCA$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Are you Calvin Lin from Brilliant ages ago? You’re part of the reason I became a mathematician!

Comment: Yes I am (and still is). Great to hear that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some:

$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1/2 & 1/2 & 0\\
1 &  0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$

$B=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1/2 & 1/2\\
0& 1 &  0 
\end{pmatrix}$

$C$ is determined by these.

Comment: Interesting. How did you come up with this example?

Comment: @user1551 By a different question I asked, I realized these are braid group representations. I knew the Bureau representation of the braid group and this is a special case. The general case replaces the first $1/2$ by $t$ and the second by $1-t$. This is discussed in a paper by Jones (the one from the Jones polynomial).

Comment: There are loads of examples since the representation theory of the braid group is wild.

Comment: My hint was leading to if $ AB=BC=CA = X$, then $ AXA = X^2$ which lead to group theory and hence representation theory for matrices. However, I wasn't certain how much you know of representation theory (which seemed like an overkill to me), hence the "possible". $\quad$ The "well known" solution to this equation is $S_3$, but that has $A^2 = I$ (which is Rioghasarig's deleted solution).

Comment: @CalvinLin Fair enough! Thanks